# Computer shuts down when I run any multithreaded code written in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, random, shutdown

I write Java code for research problems at my university, and any time I attempt to run code that I have set up for multi-threading, such as a long running data processing step in a problem, my computer will semi-randomly shutdown. I say semi-randomly because while it is generally very consistent, it sometimes does not shut the computer down. The computer will restart like nothing happened (no "Windows did not shut down properly" nonsense).

For instance, I was working on some Multilabel classification research and wanted to multithread a portion of it. I set the limit at 10 concurrent threads and the application ran just fine. I upped the limit to 20 and the computer shut off. Now logic would dictate that I could set it back down to 10 and it would run properly again. But it didn't. When I set it back to 10, it shut off once more.

One might thing its an overheating issue, but if it were, Windows would give the "this did not shut down properly" message, and it doesn't. Furthermore, I can run this with the computer completely cooled down and it still shuts off immediately.

One might think it is also possibly a deadlock issue, but I'm pretty sure I resolved any portions of the code that might cause a deadlock (furthermore, I seriously doubt that would cause the computer to shut down).

This is exceedingly annoying, and was hoping maybe someone has heard of this problem before, or knows a possible solution. Other applications I have written are plagued with the same problem on occasion, and it appears to be completely random (but consistent once it happens once).

(I would put up the code, but it doesn't appear to be code dependent. Furthermore, the code is long and somewhat annoying to read).

Edit: Checked the heat increase. Running just a second increases the heat from 86 to 97C on all four processors. So, it may very well be an overheating issue. Its kind of hard to believe that it would increase so quickly.

Comment: Err...  sounds like it's time to reinstall your JDK and/or Windows.  That should never happen.

Comment: can you check with a temperature monitor program to exclude the overheating issue?

Comment: I could do that, yeah. Good idea.

Comment: Lots of things can cause random reboots. Bad RAM, disk controllers, you name it. I had to help monitor a fleet of 12,000 PC's and the most common (hardware) problem was bad RAM. You might want to try memtestx86. http://www.memtest.org/

Comment: I'll attempt to run memtest ASAP. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like overheating, but it could be a bad power supply getting over-taxed. It's definitely not a problem with your Java code. At worst, your Java code would hang or terminate with an error. If your code can cause the JVM process to crash (not even crash the machine), there's a bug in the JVM. But this sounds like bad hardware.

Comment: Dude, if you're *starting* at 86C, you already have a serious problem. My quad core gaming rig runs at 55C under heavy (multicore) load with only forced air cooling.

Comment: Its a Clevo x7200. It tends to run fairly hot even with small tasks. Bad air ventilation or something. Not entirely sure.

Comment: No - seriously, it's more than that. That's an i7 that shouldn't be running more than 70C under heavy load. The thing goes into an overheat protection mode at 100C (right before it melts, I would imagine).

Comment: CPU load is 1~2% and the temps are averaging at 80C. Only one of my four fans appears to care (though I know the other three work). The other three are just barely blowing air out. Not sure why it is running so hot when I'm doing absolutely nothing in particular.

Comment: Though x7200's have been known to get to those temperatures under fairly heavy processes: http://forum.notebookreview.com/sager-clevo-reviews-owners-lounges/557833-tempurature-analysis-comparison-x7200.html

Comment: @erickson, random halt is definitely overheating

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem!! So glad it wasn't just me going mad all the time. :) It was because of the laptop overheat. I do not know why but it would do that with Java multithreading. I mean I would sometime watch movies in HD, games, it was hot as hell, but it would not shut down. But as soon as was doing some Java multithreading (or Message Broker Compilation in the Toolkit) it would shut down immediately. It was i5 Dell btw. I replaced it, twice - without success. Posted on the Dell forum, everyone thought I'm crazy, since it could not happen, apparently they were wrong! The thing that saved me was, well, a new Laptop. Hope you can fix your issue in a cheaper way.

One more thing, on my current laptop, a Macbook with Linux, I have control over the fans, and I wrote a script that would control fans speeds. May be you have that option also on yours?

Cheers, Eugene.